# Antec Minuet --- standoffs or no standoffs?

Tags: computer-building

I'm building an HTPC in an Antec Minuet case that I bought a couple of years ago.  The manual says to use brass standoffs under the motherboard, just like any other case I've ever used.  But if brass standoffs came with the case, I can't find them.  And when I use standoffs from another Antec case, which fit, the motherboard is mounted way too high to fit the I/O panel.

The mount holes are on little metal hills, so I suppose it's just barely possible that the motherboard mounts direct on those hills, without standoffs.  But the manual says otherwise, and I'd really rather not short out my motherboard, which is the most expensive component of my system.

Has anybody built a PC in an Antec Minuet case?  Did you use standoffs? (This case supports micro-ATX motherboards only.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [**review of the Antec Menuet**](http://www.expertreviews.co.uk/cases/248259/antec-minuet-350) describes that it does not come with standoffs:

> Unlike most cases, the Minuet 350
>   comes without any brass standoffs for
>   raising the motherboard off the back
>   panel. While the manual instructs you
>   to use standoffs, the case has several
>   raised metal domes to which you can
>   screw your microATX board directly.
>   This makes positioning the board
>   remarkably simple.

And **[this review](http://hardwarelogic.com/articles.php?id=5187)** too:

> On first glance, the inside of the
>   Minuet 300 does not show anything odd
>   or unreasonable.  About the only thing
>   worth mentioning is the fact that the
>   motherboard standoffs are built into
>   the motherboard tray (which is not
>   removeable).  I think this is a really
>   nice feature as it really helps to cut
>   down on the amount of assembly
>   required since you don't have to worry
>   about finding your own standoffs and
>   screwing them all down in the correct
>   holes.

Answer (score 2):

I personally do not use standoffs, I have not used this case but have used other Antec ones - and from the picture, it is the same.

If you take a look at your motherboard, their is a circular area near the holes and there is no active/electrical components there and there should be no risk of danger.

If you are still cautious, try finding a washer, but again, I have never had problems with these.

Generally speaking, in larger cases (full ATX) they only raise the ones required for MATX so you use the posts in the additional holes, and nothing in the raised ones.

Comment: "washer"?  that the word you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, I see the blank area underneath, but it looks small compared to the "ant hill".

Comment: @Norman Ramsey I thought the same as you, but trust me, it works! Many cases now have that and they work fine.